# How can you use selectElementContents with getElementsByClassName() to select table cells with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm attempting to create a table that can be filtered with dropdown menus and has a button that allows a user to copy the results to their clipboard. However I don't want every column to be copied to the clipboard.

After a lot of research, I think I might have come across something that may work but I'm too much of a novice to understand the errors and how to correct it.

Instead of using getElementById, I'd like to use getElementsByClassName and assign a class to the table cells (td) that I want copied. However I get this error when I hit the button:

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.**

```
<input type="button" value="Copy table to clipboard" onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementsByClassName('copy') );">

<select id="myList" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control'>
<option label="Select State"></option>
<option>US</option>
<option>CA</option>
</select>

<table class="w3-table-all w3-margin-top" id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Option 1</th>
  <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Option 2</th>
  <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Option 3</th>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="copy">ABC</td>
  <td class="copy">11</td>
  <td>US</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="copy">DEF</td>
  <td class="copy">15</td>
  <td>US</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="copy">GHI</td>
  <td class="copy">1684</td>
  <td>CA</td>

</tr>
</table>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
   var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
   input = document.getElementById("myList");
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
   for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
     td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
     if (td) {
       txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
       if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         tr[i].style.display = "";
       } else {
         tr[i].style.display = "none";
       }
     }
   }
 }
     function selectElementContents(el) {
     var body = document.body,
       range, sel;
     if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
       range = document.createRange();
       sel = window.getSelection();
       sel.removeAllRanges();
       try {
         range.selectNodeContents(el);
         sel.addRange(range);
       } catch (e) {
         range.selectNode(el);
         sel.addRange(range);
       }
     } else if (body.createTextRange) {
       range = body.createTextRange();
       range.moveToElementText(el);
       range.select();
     }
     document.execCommand("Copy");
    // window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    // document.selection.empty();

   }
</script>
```

I expect the result to copy the first two columns because they have a class of "copy" and not copy the third column. Currently nothing is being copied.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/SMErickson7/qdLr9gpn/

Comment: Pease, create a snippet with this code running, so we can reproduce the problem easily. Thank you.

Comment: Code was posted and included a JSFiddle link.